# (C++) Rows in my columns aren't showing up after the first iteration

Tags: c++, syntax, multiple-columns

I'm 2 days news to programming and this is my first post, so I'd greatly appreciate your help and patience. :)

My current assignment is to have a user input 2 items bought from a store, including price and quantity, to generate a receipt. For some reason, I can't get any of my code to display after the first item's info gets displayed.

[image: pic of problem]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> // For column organization
#include <string> // For item names

using namespace std;

const float TAX = 0.08675;

int main()
{


    string itemOne, itemTwo;
    double priceOne, priceTwo;
    int countOne, countTwo;


    cout << "Hello, what is the first item that you are purchasing    today?" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the item below." << endl;
    getline(cin, itemOne);

    cout << endl << "Thank you." << endl;
    cout << "Now enter the price and then the quantity of " + itemOne + "(s) purchased, separated by a space." << endl;
    cin >> priceOne >> countOne;
    cin.ignore();

    cout << endl << "What is the second item that you are purchasing today?\n";
    cout << "Please enter the item below." << endl;
    getline(cin, itemTwo);

    cout << endl << "Thank you." << endl;
    cout << "Now enter the price and then the quantity of " + itemTwo + "(s) purchased, separated by a space." << endl;
    cin >> priceTwo >> countTwo;

/* Calculations for the Receipt */

     float subTotal, finalPriceOne, finalPriceTwo, salesTax, finalTotal;

    finalPriceOne = countOne * priceOne;
    finalPriceTwo = countTwo * priceTwo;
    subTotal = finalPriceOne + finalPriceTwo;
    salesTax = subTotal * TAX;
    finalTotal = subTotal + salesTax;

    /* Receipt */

    cout << endl << "Your receipt has been calculated and is for your viewing below..." << endl << endl;

    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    cout << left << setw(15) << "Item";
    cout << right << setw(15) << "Quantity";
    cout << right << setw(15) << "Price";
    cout << right << setw(15) << "Ext. Price";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------\n";

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;

    cout << left << setw(15) << itemOne;
    cout << right << setw(15) << countOne;
    cout << right << setw(15) << priceOne;
    cout << right << setw(15) << finalPriceOne;
    cout << endl;

    cout << left << setw(15) << itemTwo;
    cout << right << setw(15) << countTwo;
    cout << right << setw(15) << priceTwo;
    cout << right << setw(15) << finalPriceTwo;
    cout << endl;

    cout << left << setw(15) << "Tax";
    cout << right << setw(15) << salesTax;
    cout << endl;

    cout << left << setw(15) << "Total";
    cout << right << setw(15) << finalTotal;
    cout << endl;


    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: can you show the output ([edit] the question)?

Comment: I added a picture link to my post.

Comment: ok you would have to step through the endl since standard output would be flushed. It isn't now.

Comment: By step through the endl, do you mean don't include it and just carry onto the next item?

Comment: have you tried to run your program on a standard console (not your IDE)?

Comment: I apologize for my incompetence as I'm new to programming, but what's a standard console I can dl to run c++ on? I'm currently using xcode and had no problem displaying code up till now.

Comment: a terminal / shell whatever.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer (Windows g++ CodeBlocks) everything is fine. The problem surely comes from your IDE. Here is your code output on my screen : 
[image]

Just for information, try to use C++ functionalities as POO to dsign your objects. It will be easier for you when coding bigger applications.

Comment: Thanks! My teacher recommended codeblocks for windows and xcode for macs, but i'll dl another IDE.

Comment: Also, how would I go about aligning my "tax" and "total" numbers on the right side under "ext. price"?

Comment: put setw(45) instead of setw(15) for the Tax and Total :
`    cout << left << setw(45) << "Tax";
    cout << right << setw(15) << salesTax;
    cout << endl;

    cout << left << setw(45) << "Total";
    cout << right << setw(15) << finalTotal;
    cout << endl;`

Comment: @herryJan It's the wrong way to go "I'll download another IDE" when something goes wrong. Xcode is a good environment, learn what went wrong and keep using it. Another IDE might have another quirk...

Answer (score 0):

I think your execution is just paused at that breakpoint on the `endl` for the second item. If you step past it (or just remove the breakpoint), does the whole line for the second item appear? If so, it's because of something called "line buffering", where the program doesn't actually output as soon as you tell it to, but instead it collects up things until it sees a line-ending and then it outputs the whole line.

(Breakpoints, in case it's something you did by accident, are a feature of interactive debugging systems where you can have the whole program pause before executing a given line of code. They're often set in IDEs via a right-click menu or a click in the margin next to the line of code.)